# submit multiple forms on one page

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

I have a searchbar and a comment form on one page. The searchbar has some nice little features, like livesearch und suggestion and is submitted via [ENTER]. The comment form is validated by the jquery-validate plugin and submitted by clicking the submit button.

The searchbar is working perfect on pages where it is the only form, but on pages with comment form enabled the submitting with [ENTER] won't work.

What can I do to make this possible?

Code looks like this:

Search:

```
<form  action="/goto/doSearch.php">
    <label>Search</label>
    <input id="searchBox" type="text" name="search" value="type and hit enter">
</form>
```

Comment:

```
<form id="rating" action="/goto/doComment.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1"></input>
      <label for="cname">Name</label>
      <input class="required" id="cname" type="text" value="Your name" name="author">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Elaborate on "submitting with [ENTER] won't work".

Comment: the commentform is submitted by pressing enter.

Comment: added method="get" to the first form, now its working. nvm

Answer (score 1):

One solution I could see for your problem would be to make a button for your search field.  So that on click it will go to the desired page.  If anything, this will help you to diagnose the problem further.  Just make sure to name it something besides "submit".

For example...

```
<input type="submit" name="search" class="btn" value="Search">
```

Otherwise, I noticed in your code you have an `id` for the `comment form` but not for the `search form`... this might be an issue, but without more details I am unsure.